# Namespace and classes with its methods definitions in single header file.How can use it in more than one header or cpp file?

Tags: c++

Actually, It is working fine when I include in single cpp file, however,on including more than one file, it's giving already defined in other obj. This file is quite large and I have download for my project.How can I use this file in more than one cpp.

I am using visual studio 2019.

Error:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2005 "struct objl::Vector3 __cdecl objl::algorithm::operator*(float const &,struct objl::Vector3 const &)" (??Dalgorithm@objl@@YA?AUVector3@1@ABMABU21@@Z) already defined in OpenGLControl.obj

Comment: All questions here should have all relevant information ***in the question itself as plain text***. Links can stop working at any time making questions meaningless. Code, data, or errors shown as images cannot be copy/pasted; or edited or compiled for further research and investigation. Please [edit] this question, removing and replacing all links and images with all relevant information as plain text. All code must meet all requirements of a [mre]. You can find many other questions here that explain everything in plain text, please use them as an example for how your question should look.

Comment: What compiler? And narrow down your code to a _minimal_ example _in_ the question please.

Comment: try inline & external

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to mark your function definitions `inline`.  That's what the `inline` keyword is for: it allows a function or object to be defined in multiple translation units so long as all of the definitions are identical.  Remember that including a header file does nothing but paste the text from that header into another file.  Any functions defined in that header file will be defined in every translation unit the header gets included into, and if they are not marked `inline` that will violate the One Definition Rule.

Note that function definitions within class definitions are implicitly `inline`, so you don't need to explicitly mark those `inline`.